# FireBase Data Retrieval is getting so much time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase to retrieve data and display it on android. At first it was fine but now it is taking 10 sec on addValueUpdateListner anyone know what is the problem? 
    final String uid1=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

```
DatabaseReference 

dbref1=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users")
.child(uid1)
.child("signUpAs");
dbref1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
signUpOption=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),signUpOption,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
}
});
```

Comment: You said at first it was fine using the same code?

Comment: yes exactly the same code @NickZisis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ValueEventListener retrieves all the data at once so if your database grew up in size, it makes sense to take more time than before.

Comment: how can we stop the next code executing while  getting data from valueEventListner